# Collapsible Lists in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list

How can I build a SharePoint 2010 list like the one in this screen?

[image]

Original page here: http://wssv3faq.mindsharp.com/Lists/v3%20WSS%20FAQ/V%20Books.aspx

Answer (score 5):

That is standard Grouping, you can modify grouping in a View of a list or library.

For example in the GUI by navigating to your list, or library, 
Select "List" or "Library" from the ribbon and click "Modify view".

Under the Grouping header (by the way, you can se grouping is actually used on this page!) you can select what to group by, and weither Groups should be collapsed or expanded by default

Comment: spot on +1, you just beat me to it :(

Answer (score 3):

That is a standard view with a group by option.

You need to edit a view on your list (or create a new view) and then select the field you want to group by on. In the view setting page you need to set this property.

[image]

Leave a note if you need more guidance.